Is there a similar graph-like structure to the one shown in the combinatorial game Sprouts?
In Sprouts, a game is not strictly represented as a graph; it has similar properties to a graph (i.e. you can move vertices and edges in the same region without consequence), but sprouts has regions in which vertices and edges can't be taken out of when it is being manipulated.
Is there a structure analyzed similarly in graph theory that has similar properties? The way that Glop represents games is by enclosing vertices in certain regions, but it doesn't make any indication of similar structures in its README or its original paper.

The structure of a graph drawn into the plane is called a planar map. In Sprouts you consider subcubic non-simple planar maps, i.e. planar maps of graphs with degrees at most three where self-loops are allowed.
Some properties of planar maps are studied by graph theorists, for example their enumeration by a formula involving Catalan numbers (Tutte's theorem).
